# Xcode crashed when I try to drag CollectionView to storyboard

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xamarin.mac

I am developing Xamarin.Mac application and so I am using Xcode interface builder. My problem is: every time I try to drag CollectionView from library onto my View, Xcode crashes. However, if I try to drag other elements, they work fine. How can I fix it and where should I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, later I discovered that if I create a new project and drag CollectionView to one of the views there, it works fine. Only in my project it  crashes only when I add CollectionView specifically
I ended up just creating a new project, adding CollectionView to it and copying markup of this element to my project's storyboard file. It worked great